# Seeking help configuring apache server in 10.7 to work with squid cachemgr.cgi

Tags: apache-2.2, squid

The setup is...

[/usr/local/etc/cachemgr.conf](http://pastebin.com/JBZknXin)

```
# This file controls which servers may be managed by
# the cachemgr.cgi script
#
# The file consists of one server per line on the format
#   hostname:port  description
#
# Specifying :port is optional. If not specified then
# the default proxy port is assumed. :* or :any matches
# any port on the target server.
#
# hostname is matched using shell filename matching, allowing
# * and other shell wildcards.
localhost:3128
```

[/usr/local/etc/squid.conf](http://pastebin.com/Az8gpLu1)

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object 
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow all
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
#http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 192.168.1.150:3128 transparent

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /usr/local/var/cache 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /usr/local/var/cache

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320


cachemgr_passwd none all
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
visible_hostname test.cache
```

[/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/Az8gpLu1)

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#
acl manager proto cache_object 
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow all
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
#http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 192.168.1.150:3128 transparent

# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
cache_dir ufs /usr/local/var/cache 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /usr/local/var/cache

# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320


cachemgr_passwd none all
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
visible_hostname test.cache
```

I go to http://localhost/
 and attempt to connect to cachemgr.cgi and I get:

> Cache Manager Error connect 127.0.0.1:3128: (61) Connection refused
>   Generated Tue, 08 May 2012 01:06:31 GMT, by
>   cachemgr.cgi/3.1.9@admins-macbook-pro.local

any help would be great.

Running 10.7.x with a homebrew port of Squid installed and working as a transparent server 
and I hacked at Apache for it to work with cgi's.  I think maybe configuring the root Apache server and not the "~" Apache server is the issue. I am not really sure. If I could get a little help getting Squid's cachemgr.cgi to run in the "~" webserver I think that might take care of the issue? Also how would I get that to work without hacking around at it? Because I have no idea how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

cachemgr is trying to connect to Squid via localshot and you have the proxy listening on an specific interface. Remove the IP address in the http_port statement.